# Calculating sinusoidity of a line

Tags: geometry

I have a line in a 2D plane. I wanted to calculate the sinusoidity of the line. What i thought was to calculate the arc length and then divide this with the eucledean distance between the initial and final points of the line. Is this a correct procedure?

Comment: Define the sinusoidity. Currently, Google reports 61 occurrences of this word, which is a good sign that it doesn't exist.

Comment: how straight a curve is..

Comment: If you have no precise requirement, this method is not worse than another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the [radius of curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature) at any point where the second derivative is defined by $$R=\left|\frac {(1+y')^{3/2}}{y''}\right|$$

Your approach is a fine algorithm.  Whether it matches what you are looking for is up to you.  Note that it will not distinguish two sides of a triangle from a rather smooth curve of the same arc length and end points.